# Including test Playframework sbt projects inside the sbt project for a Playframework library

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, integration-testing

I work on a few Scala libraries that are based on the Playframework ([`play-git-hub`](https://github.com/rtyley/play-git-hub), [`play-googleauth`](https://github.com/guardian/play-googleauth), [`play-secret-rotation`](https://github.com/guardian/play-secret-rotation)), and I'd like to include some full 'test' Playframework sbt projects within the tests for those projects.

Of the projects listed above, `play-googleauth` pushes the main library code down one level (into [`module`](https://github.com/guardian/play-googleauth/tree/aca65d3e/module)) in order to allow the [`example`](https://github.com/guardian/play-googleauth/tree/aca65d3e/example) project to sit next to it - which works, but I'd rather have the library sit at the root of the project if possible, and the test examples pushed down in the file hierarchy.

I can see that in the Playframework itself, there are several `sbt-test` folders that sit within the `src` folders of various modules - these folders contain full sbt projects (eg [`sbt-plugin/src/sbt-test`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/c038bc147/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/sbt-test)), exactly like how I'd like to have them. I can't find any documentation for `sbt-test` folders though - is this a Play thing or an sbt thing? What enables them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an sbt thing. You can configure sbt with a [multi-project layout](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html) and add some plugins .

You can look at the play [build](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c038bc147b03285a1de7acc50037e1e7f438bedf/framework/build.sbt#L180) [files](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c038bc147b03285a1de7acc50037e1e7f438bedf/framework/project/BuildSettings.scala#L560) to get an idea of how they manage it. They also use [interplay](https://github.com/playframework/interplay) for common behaviour. You might want to look into it.

Comment: Looking through those links, I notice that `sbt-test` isn't mentioned anywhere - so `sbt-test` isn't a special string here, the folder could be named `foobarbaz` and it would still work?

Comment: Seems like `sbt-test` comes from an other plugin [scripted-plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html)  that `interplay` brings